# How to add an ar object on a small image in a real world

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am working on a application where I have to place an ar object on a icon whose size is not big in a real world.I followed augmented Image codelabs example for an image which is working but when I added an icon in the example and tried to locate it in the real world I found that onUpdateFrame was not getting called.Is is possible to achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There are few questions: 
What is the score you get from arcoreimg tool?
What is the size of the real image?

Comment: I did'nt use arcoring tool.I followed the codelab example and just replaced the image with qr code. But it does not scan

Comment: for Augmented Images to recognize your new image you need to add it into database. In the sample you have a file sample_database.imgdb. There the earth image is registered with arcoreimg. You need to do the same for your new image. Check the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/arcoreimg#create_an_image_database_file

Comment: I will try the same.But when I changed the image from codelab example to a new image it worked fine but I added a qr core it failed

Comment: Your QR might not work because the score of the image is low. Here about image quality. ARCore recommends it to be above 75 to wor good https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images/arcoreimg#check_image_quality